# Attempting to mock child method, fails if parent module imports it using object destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I was doing some basic jest unit testing in attempt to learn it more.

I have this issue I do not know how to explain

This file has the child function add

```
// FileB.js 

const add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = {
  add,
};
```

This file has the parent function addTen

```
// FileA.js

const { add } = require('./FileB');

const addTen = num => {
  return add(10, num);
}

module.exports = {
  addTen,
};
```

this is my test file, where I am trying to either check `<mockedFunction/spy>.mock.calls` or do `toHaveBeenCalledWith` to see if the inner child method, add, is being passed in 10,10 when i call `addTen(10);`

This file is not used in any real env, its simply me trying to learn jest + unit testing more.

```
// randomTest.js

const { addTen } = require('../src/FileA');
const fileB = require('../src/FileB'); 

describe('temp', () => {
  it('temp', () => {
    const addSpy = jest.spyOn(fileB, 'add');

    addTen(10);
    console.log(addSpy.mock.calls);

    expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10,10)
  });
});
```

Now for the issue, the test fails, saying `add` was never called, or nothing passed in. I logged the add function within `FileB`

However, if I modify `FileA` in this way, by importing entore module instead of destructuring, the test passes and I cna log out the functions and everything and see it works

This is what works

```
// FileA.js

const fileB = require('./FileB');

const addTen = num => {
  return fileB.add(10, num);
}

module.exports = {
  addTen,
};
```

Why does this slight change work? And is there a way to avoid this and keep my destrcutoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting up your spy before importing `addTen` from `FileA`

```
const fileB = require('./FileB'); 
const spy = jest.spyOn(fileB, 'add');

const {addTen} = require('./FileA');

describe('temp', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    // restore the spy created with spyOn
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('temp', () => {
    addTen(10);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10,10)
  });
});
```

Or, you can mock `./FileB` with [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

```
const mockAdd = jest.fn()
jest.mock('./FileB', ()=> {
  return {
    add: mockAdd
  }
});

const {addTen} = require('./FileA');

describe('temp', () => {
  it('temp', () => {
    addTen(10);
    expect(mockAdd).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10,10)
  });
});
```

In both cases, you want your `FileA` to import a mocked function from `FileB`, so you would do that before importing it.

Not that `jest.mock` would be hoisted anyways, so even if you don't put it at the beginning of your file, it would be moved there on the runtime

---

Now back to your first question "Why deconstructing the imported object make the test fail?"

First, let's remember that JavaScript pass Objects by reference. Which means the following:

```
const a = {
  b: 1
}

const c = a;
c.b = 9;

console.log(a); // will print { b: 9 }
```

Which means when `FileA` imports `const { add } = require("./FileB")` you are using the reference to the function `add` (functions are objects in JavaScript).

This leads to having the reference of the real `add` function in `addTen`, and then even if you use `spyOn` to override `FileB.add` you won't rewrite what `addTen` already has.

Now in case you use `const fileB = require("./FileB")` in `FileA`, you get a reference of **the object** that has `add`, that same object that you override with `jest.spyOn`.

That also explains what happens when you run the spyOn before importing addTen:

```
it("should pass", () => {
  const addSpy = jest.spyOn(fileB, "add");
  const { addTen } = require("../FileA");
  addTen(10);
  expect(addSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10, 10);
});
```

`FileB.add`'s reference will be replaced with the new mock's reference, see how this is happening under the hood: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e2196cab463c5a3e15668b1d7663058b09b7c0ed/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L1256.

Comment: hello, how does putting spy before the import change this behavior? to me, its confusing that when you test module a, that imports b, it doesnt allow a spy unless its not destructored, i dont understand that and why it acts that why...

Comment: Also, wouldn't this mean u have one spy for all test vs declaring spy per test? @Fcmam5

Comment: [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) creates a mock on your `object[methodName]`, that's why you have to pass your object and its methods, if you are exporting an object from `moduleB` you have to instruct jest to change your `add` function inside that object so `spy` would act on `moduleBExportedObject["add"]`

Comment: And yes, you will have a spy function for all tests with that example, but that would be fine as `spy` function calls the original one, and you can always reset your mock by calling [`jest.restoreAllMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrestoreallmocks) in `afterEach` hook, I will update my example above

Comment: thanks i am learning, but im stil la bit confused on destructing breaks this and why declaring a spy before i import a module (which imports said module) fixes it

Comment: sorry if was not clear. You have to setup your spy **before importing** your method (using destructured or not) so you replace the function in `FileB` **before** you import anything from `FileA`

Comment: I just updated my answer with an answer about the distructuring part